# nginx in docker how to disable http redirects to https

Tags: curl, nginx, docker

I am trying to deploy meteor app in digitalocean with docker container.  I have done setup application in two web dockers and one nginx docker. I forked [this image](https://github.com/meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server) repo to build docker. you can see nginx config under lib directory. here nginx is configured with SSL and requested to web docker. I faced some issues to generated SSL certificate to the ipaddress. App is under development so planned to remove SSL for now. so changed Nginx config.

```
daemon off;
error_log /dev/stdout notice;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream site{
      server backend1:80;
      server backend2:80;
    }

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen              80 default_server;
        server_name         mup-ssl; //tried mup-ssl; and _;
        client_max_body_size 10M;


        location / {
          proxy_pass http://site/;
          proxy_redirect      off;
          proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Connection        "upgrade";

          #
          # Specific for comet or long running HTTP requests, don't buffer up the
          # response from origin servers but send them directly to the client.
          #
          proxy_buffering     off;

          #
          # Bump the timeout's so someting sensible so our connections don't
          # disconnect automatically. We've set it to 12 hours.
          #
          proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;
          proxy_read_timeout    43200000;
          proxy_send_timeout    43200000;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I hit `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx` in brower it redirected to `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx`. How should I disable https? redirect.

curl response:

```
curl -i http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 18:09:11 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/

curl -i https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 443: Connection refused
```

Comment: Could it be that your app is issuing the redirect?

Comment: You may want to remove the tag [docker] as it has nothing to do with it ;)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am also getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose, add just : HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect in environment.
Like this

```html
service:
    container_name: name
    restart: always
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
    env_file:
      - .env
```

: